# JavaScript create a dictionary - missing key

Tags: javascript, dictionary

If I try to create a dictionary this way:

```
var dict = [];
$.each(objs, function (idx, obj) {
    dict[obj.category] = obj;
});
```

Old elements with the same `category` are overwritten and each key only has one value, if I do it this way:

```
var dict = [];
$.each(objs, function (idx, obj) {
    dict[obj.category].push(obj);
});
```

I get an error if the key doesn't exist. How can I solve this problem? I basically want a dictionary which looks like this:

```
"Category1":{obj1,obj2,obj3},
"Category2":{obj4,obj5,obj6}
```

Comment: dict[obj.category] is null before you initialize it so you are basically doing null.push(obj)

Comment: Dictionaries can't be simulated with Arrays. For that, you need an Object, which has key, value pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first off use an object since arrays have numeric indexing

Create an array if the category key doesn't exist

```
var dict ={};
$.each(objs, function (idx, obj) {
    // if key exists use existing array or assign a new empty array
    dict[obj.category] = dict[obj.category] || [] ;
    dict[obj.category].push(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the property exists and if not assign an empty array.

Then push the value.

```
dict[obj.category] = dict[obj.category] || [];
dict[obj.category].push(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is good to simulate `{}` for dictionary, but for dictionary logic it will be better to use **[Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)** to work on higher level of abstraction. Check if the object has a key, if not create and assign to it an array, if already has - just push into it.

```
const map = new Map();

$.each(objs, function (idx, obj) {

    if(!map.has(obj.category)) {
       map.set(obj.category, []);
    }

    map.get(obj.category).push(obj);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an object.

```
let dict = {};
dict.Category1 = {};
dict.Category2 = {};
console.log(dict.hasOwnProperty('Category1'), dict.hasOwnProperty('Category3'));

for (item in dict) {
  console.log(item, dict[item]);
}
```